# Add single user to all folder security permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I need to add a user to the security permissions on all folders in a windows 7 file structure.  The problem is that I can't enforce inheritance, because only the one user needs access and that would give too many users access to certain locked subfolders (of which there are very many).

Is there any way to do this?  I've been searching and playing around with permissions but the only thing I've found so far is forcing inheritance to the subfolders...

Answer (score 0):

`cacls.exe` is your friend with some options:

- /T: Recurse
- /E: **Edit** ACLs so leaving others untouched
- /G: Grant

So you end up with

```
cacls X:\some\folder /T /E /G username:F
```